# Loop from array not executed

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on an android app that should create some records on a MySQL database.

This is the PHP file that receives the POST values from the app.
As you may see, there are three arrays that collect specific POST. 
The first and second loops are working fine and executing the related guardar_post_media() function.

But the third loop is not executed and there are real values on the variables inside the third array.

May be there is something wrong that I can´t detect, may be you can.

```
<?php
        require_once '../mis_php_functions/funciones_basicas.php';

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

            $val39 = $_POST['val39']; 
            $val40 = $_POST['val40']; 
            $val46 = $_POST['val46']; 
            $val48 = $_POST['val48']; 
            $val50 = $_POST['val50']; 
            $val52 = $_POST['val52']; 
            $val54 = $_POST['val54']; 
            $val56 = $_POST['val56']; 
            $val58 = $_POST['val58']; 
            $val60 = $_POST['val60']; 
            $val62 = $_POST['val62']; 
            $val64 = $_POST['val64']; 
            $val65 = $_POST['val65']; 
            $val67 = $_POST['val67']; 
            $val69 = $_POST['val69']; 
            $val71 = $_POST['val71'];
            $val73 = $_POST['val73'];
            $val75 = $_POST['val75'];
            $val77 = $_POST['val77'];
            $val79 = $_POST['val79'];
            $val81 = $_POST['val81'];
            $val82 = $_POST['val82'];
            $val83 = $_POST['val83'];
            $val84 = $_POST['val84'];
            $val85 = $_POST['val85'];
            $val86 = $_POST['val86'];
            $val87 = $_POST['val87'];
            $val88 = $_POST['val88'];
            $val89 = $_POST['val89'];
            $val100 = $_POST['val100'];
            $val101 = $_POST['val101'];
            $val102 = $_POST['val102'];
            $val103 = $_POST['val103'];
            $val104 = $_POST['val104'];
            $status = 1;



             $post = guardar_post($val40,$val39,$val100,$val102,$status,$val103);

     if ($post != false) {


            $fotos = array($val48,$val50,$val52,$val54,$val56,$val58,$val60,$val62,$val64);


        $arrayLength = count($fotos);
        echo "Numero de fotos ".$arrayLength;
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $arrayLength)
        {


            if ($fotos[$i] == 0){

            }
            else{
                guardar_post_media(1,$fotos[$i],$val102,$val100,$post);
            }


            echo "<br />".$fotos[$i] ."<br />";
            $i++;
        }

   $videos = array($val67,$val69,$val71,$val73,$val75,$val77,$val79,$val81,$val83);


        $arrayLength2 = count($videos);
        echo "Numero de videos ".$arrayLength2;
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $arrayLength2)
        {


            if ($videos[$i] == 0){

            }
            else{

                guardar_post_media(2,$videos[$i],$val102,$val100,$post);
            }


            echo "<br />".$videos[$i] ."<br />";
            $i++;
        }

   $youtube = array($val85,$val86,$val87,$val88,$val89);


        $arrayLength3 = count($youtube);
        echo "Numero de youtube ".$arrayLength3;
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $arrayLength3)
        {


            if ($youtube[$i] == 0){

            }
            else{

                guardar_post_media(3,$youtube[$i],$val102,$val100,$post);
            }


            echo "<br />".$youtube[$i] ."<br />";
            $i++;
        }



            sendMessageNuevoPost($val39,$val102,$val103,$val104); // envio de push





        }
        else{
            echo 'error';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What a nice way of filtering arrays :)

Comment: Here there's something you can use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: @TahaPaksu, I am here to learn. I appreciate all improving proposals.

Comment: Why didn't you use the array directly and assigned each of it into variables? You can do `guardar_post($_POST['val101'], ... `

Comment: @04FS, I am using the echo statements to check if the POST values are received or not.

Comment: @TahaPaksu, you are right, but not all POST values are eligible for guardar_post() function.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If you are getting a positive result for your `Numero de youtube` debug output, but then nothing from inside the while loop - then perhaps your script got killed because of some fatal error caused by `guardar_post_media` …

Comment: … or all the `$youtube[$i]` values you are outputting inside the loop via echo might be just whitespace, who knows.

Comment: _“but not all POST values are eligible for guardar_post() function”_ - so what, that still doesn’t require that you do `$varXY = $_POST['XY']` countless times, you might as well insert `$_POST['XY']` in all the places where you are currently using `$varXY`. If you are not doing any extended validation (like check if POST values are set, and if not set a default value or something), then this is just plain pointless copying values from one variable into another for no good reason.

Comment: @04FS `count($youtube)` will always be 5 even if each element of that array is empty, because of the way the array was defined.

Comment: @TahaPaksu please do not suggest use of `extract()` on unsafe arrays like `$_POST`, `$_GET`...

Comment: @MichalHynčica, that's something to learn for a beginner, and something to stay away after he got experience.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yeah, of course … but if perhaps no proper error reporting is enabled, then any typos in variables names might cause issues as well (easy enough to check in that particular place as well, of course) – so I’d rather get explicit confirmation.

Comment: @mvasco, what kind of values are you storing to the POST vars. Could you give an example? At all do you store non-numerical data in particular at times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
if ($youtube[$i] == 0){

}
else {

}
```

But POST vars are all strings. Change to:

```
if ($youtube[$i] == "0"){

}
else {

}
```

In otherwords, an equality on a string to numerical 0 will be true in your cases. And thus your `else` never executes.

*** Edit. PROOF

```
$test1 = "filename.dat";
$test2 = "2939";
$test3 = "some useful data";
$test4 = "0";

if ($test1 == 0) {
    // Dont do anything
}
else {
    echo "Do Work 1.";
}

if ($test2 == 0) {
    // Dont do anything
}
else {
    echo "Do Work 2.";
}

if ($test3 == 0) {
    // Dont do anything
}
else {
    echo "Do Work 3.";
}

if ($test4 == 0) {
    // Dont do anything
}
else {
    echo "Do Work 4.";
}
```

Only echoes out `Do Work 2.`. All other `echo()`s are not run because the equality of a string to a number 0 will return `true` except in those cases where the string also is numerical, and then the interpreter will compare the numerical values.

As how this relates to the OP's question: It can be inferred that the OP's POST vars must contain some non-numerical data because the OP insists that the 3rd array is populated:

> But the third loop is not executed and there are real values on the variables inside the third array.

I will add likely the loop is executed, but not giving the expected the results due the reasons so mentioned.

Tested on PHP 5 and 7.

Comment: @mvasco, what kind of values are you storing to the POST vars. Could you give an example? At all do you store non-numerical data in particular at times?

Comment: @GetSet, they will store string values

Comment: @mvasco Thats the answer i was waiting for. Have a look at my solution above which may address your problem.

Comment: You are, changing the comparison to =="0" solves the issue.

Comment: Excellent. Was curious.